# Logging a user in java

Tags: logging

• Implement logic to read a text file • The file will contain on each line some data: userID and password: e.g. : alexP92 myPass Ioan1 testPas • You should login/logout with any users from the file on console without restarting the project • For each action you should display: “Welcome username”, “Wrong username/password”, “Successfully logout”
Use Logging instead of  sysout

Comment: Please help me with this problem

Comment: What happens?
What did you expect to happen?

Comment: I should login/logout with any user from the file on console without restarting the project

Comment: Logging a user from the file on console without restarting the project